# How do I get file permissions and absolute paths in powershell exactly like ls -l in Linux?

Tags: bash, powershell

I need it on 1 line and with out the headers showing.

For example

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 u584422 qosmon1  1024 Jun  7 08:34 Daily
drwxr-xr-x 2 u584422 qosmon1  1024 May 26 10:41 Downloads
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Your question is very vague so we have no idea what you're trying to do. You really need to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as this will help you figure out what your question is missing and why it's being downvoted.

Comment: Currently, I'm using "Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }" to get the most similar version of ls -l but instead of putting the directory above, I need it to show the full path of all files in C:\ so I can put it in a database late and retrieve it, as well as it's permissions.

Comment: I pretty much need the Permissions and absolute path on 1 line

Comment: Edit your question and post it properly.

Comment: You guys understand my need now?

Comment: Please ***edit your question*** to include extant code, and samples of both current problematical output and hypothetical desired output.   SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regarding permissions: NTFS doesn't use user/group/world but rather access control lists (ACLs). So I don't think the permissions part is as straightforward as you think.

Comment: I've revised my question, does it sound more clear now?

Comment: Permissions in Linux are handled differently from those in Windows, as @Bill_Stewart indicates. Please provide an example of the Windows output you are receiving, describe what the problem is with it, and then some hypothetical output the way you want it.

Comment: I'm using Get-ChildItem and I get the name column, but I need it to not just return the filename, but the fullpath. For example c:\users\John and if possible can I get rid of the column name?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Directory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Note: The `-Directory` parameter works only in PowerShell 3.0 or later. If you have PowerShell 2.0, you will need to add `| Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer }` before the `| Select-Object` part.

Comment: But when I do this... I don't see permissions as well...?

Comment: See comments on your question regarding permissions.

Comment: Please, I'm new to Powershell, and I'm confused - do you mind assisting me with that part Bill?

Comment: Windows file system permissions are different from unix style permissions. They are access control lists, not user/group/world. See the responses to your question (as already noted).

Comment: I know that, it's the ACL command, but I need to put the data into a database, with the absolute path and permissions/control list information on each line for all files in C:\

Comment: Do a search for "Windows permission report tool".